# Parse.com javascript sdk nested save

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, sdk

I know this was possible in the Java SDK for Parse. But given a situation where I have a parse object A that will point to another object B that will to another object C.

By setting all of their fields correctly is it possible to just save object A and have the nested objects be saved automatically

Thanks,
Karan Shah

Comment: yes.  just save objectA and B and C will get saved, too.

Comment: I have tried that and I get object unsaved error.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Parse cannot be set to fields until they have been saved.

You need to save C, then B, then A.

This can be achieved with Parse promises.

```
var C = Parse.Object.extend("C"); // Or whatever objects they are
var B = Parse.Object.extend("B");
var A = Parse.Object.extend("A");
C.save().then(function()
{
    B.set("C", C);
    return B.save();

}).then(function()
{
    A.set("B", B);
    return A.save();

}).then(function()
{
    console.log("All saved successfully!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it works that way however in the Parse SDK for Java it works like that

Answer (score 0):

Actually as of 2020/1 you can [save them all at once](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#saving-nested-objects).

Use the optional argument in save(opts).

```
const Child = Parse.Object.extend("Child");
const child = new Child();

const Parent = Parse.Object.extend("Parent");
const parent = new Parent();

parent.save({ child: child });
// Automatically the object Child is created on the server
// just before saving the Parent
```